# Salesforce entry event required field

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have the following setup.

- Multi-Org with multiple market specific BU‘s
- One Salesforce org for all markets
- SF Connector at each Business Unit to the same SF Org

We‘re currently facing one issue. Everything was working fine so far, as we didn‘t used Journey Builder with SF events. So far we had different Salesforce profiles for each Connector user, that limited the access to the market specific leads (via sharing rules based on one marketID field on the lead). This  setup made sure that only the correct leads are visible and only those have been synchronized via data stream.

Now we need to setup different journeys based on lead criteria that need to be triggered in real time. We recognized that the connected user that is activating journeys with SF entry events needs additional permissions in Salesforce. Especially the user needs to have „modify all data“ checkbox activated in his profiles, since the SF journey will create a Salesforce flow in the background.

The problem here: as soon as we give the profile the „modify all data“ permission, all the lead records from the others markets would be synced via data stream. (However: we would be able to handle that in someway, by providing a Master Data Extension that would be filtered on MarketId via SQL).

But the real problem for us is the following: As a user would create a new journey based on salesforce entry events and would forget the special marketID from Salesforce as a filter criteria, he would basically inject all leads, not only the brand specific ones. Is there somehow a way to add a required field to the salesforce entry event even with some development efforts. Have anyone else had this scenario as well – how have you solved it?